# I am getting only text and images: Wordpress REST API app in Android studio

Tags: java, android, wordpress

I'm new to android app programming. I have a webview that shows the post content, but I am only getting text and images, please tell me how to change `loadData` to `loadUrl`

My classes :

**1. MainActivity.java**

```
package com.a000webhostapp.androidgrid.androidgridapp;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button layout;
    RelativeLayout fragmentContent, homeContent;
    final static String urlAddress = "https://androidgrid.000webhostapp.com/index.php/feed/";
    String url = "http://androidgrid.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=10&fields=id,title,link";
    List<Object> list;
    Gson gson;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    ListView postList;
    Map<String,Object> mapPost;
    Map<String,Object> mapTitle;
    int postID;
    String postTitle[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        postList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.postList);
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                gson = new Gson();
                list = (List) gson.fromJson(s, List.class);
                postTitle = new String[list.size()];

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();++i){
                    mapPost = (Map<String,Object>)list.get(i);
                    mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                    postTitle[i] = (String) mapTitle.get("rendered");
                }

                postList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,postTitle));
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        rQueue.add(request);

        postList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                mapPost = (Map<String,Object>)list.get(position);
                postID = ((Double)mapPost.get("id")).intValue();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Post.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", ""+postID);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }

}
```

**2. Post.java**

```
 package com.a000webhostapp.androidgrid.androidgridapp;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.android.volley.Request;
    import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
    import com.android.volley.Response;
    import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
    import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import java.util.Map;

    public class Post extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView title;
        WebView content;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        Gson gson;
        Map<String, Object> mapPost;
        Map<String, Object> mapTitle;
        Map<String, Object> mapContent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post);

        final String id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        content = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.content);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Post.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.show();

        String url = "http://androidgrid.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/"+id+"?fields=title,content";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                gson = new Gson();
                mapPost = (Map<String, Object>) gson.fromJson(s, Map.class);
                mapTitle = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("title");
                mapContent = (Map<String, Object>) mapPost.get("content");

                title.setText(mapTitle.get("rendered").toString());
                content.loadData(mapContent.get("rendered").toString(),"text/html","UTF-8");

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Post.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Post.this);
        rQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filtered the result. You can use this URL to get full post:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/
```

You can also get by categories:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=1
```

As you see you had to pass category id and all categories can get by:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/
```

You can also get paged result by:

```
http://yourwebsite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?categories=1&page=2
```

If you wan to get **post images**, check this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/299655/141031) and if you want to implement **OAuth** for better security for your apis check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49872154/can-not-set-oauth-on-wordpress-rest-api). I hope this helps.